# Using group-components with SGE cluster profile

Tags: python, snakemake

Hey Snakemake Community,

I am transitioning from a cluster with SLURM, which worked seamlessly with Snakemake, to a cluster with SGE, which seems much less supported. I've gotten most of my workflows working with the [Snakemake SGE profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/sge) but I've run into issues with some of the more complicated options like [group and --group-components](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/grouping.html).

For example, when I try to submit a job with group name, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/wrobinso/.config/snakemake/sge/sge-submit.py", line 273, in 
> print(submit_job(jobscript, qsub_settings))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/home/wrobinso/.config/snakemake/sge/sge-submit.py", line 220, in submit_job
> batch_options = flatten([sge_option_string(k,v).split() for k, v in qsub_settings["options"].items()])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/home/wrobinso/.config/snakemake/sge/sge-submit.py", line 220, in 
> batch_options = flatten([sge_option_string(k,v).split() for k, v in qsub_settings["options"].items()])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/home/wrobinso/.config/snakemake/sge/sge-submit.py", line 202, in sge_option_string
> return format_job_properties(f"-{key} {val}")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/home/wrobinso/.config/snakemake/sge/sge-submit.py", line 134, in format_job_properties
> return string.format(rulename=job_properties['rule'], jobid=job_properties['jobid'])
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
> KeyError: 'rule'
> Error submitting jobscript (exit code 1):

It seems like the profile isn't set up to handle grouped jobs (i.e. submitting multiple snakemake jobs as a single SGE job). Can anyone help suggest a fix for this? I have already tweaked the [Snakemake SGE profile](https://github.com/Snakemake-Profiles/sge) to get it running on my institution's cluster so I'm going to try to fix it myself but I would really appreciate it if a Snakemake dev could explain it better/help me? I'd be happy to contribute the solution back as a PR.

Best, Welles